# Disabling a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm facing the next problem.

I have a `RecyclerView` with the `Adapter`, the items, etc.
What I need is: Select an item in the recycler, change the color of that item, and then I have to disable the rest of the other items. It's like a `RadioButton` list.
I select one and disable the others. If I select again the same item, enable all the list.
I already have the onClick `Button` listener. I need to know if I have to reload again de list, If I have to loop and disable item by item, etc.

Thanks

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Human> humans;
private HumanClick selectedHuman;

@Inject
public MyAdapter() {

}

public void init(List<Human> humanList, SelectedHumanClick humanClick){
    this.humans = humanList;
    this.humanClick = humanClick;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_Human, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Human human = Humans.get(position);
    holder.bind(Humans.get(position));
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedHumanClick.onSelectedHumanClick(Human);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return humans != null ? Humans.size() : 0;
}

public final class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.text_view_human_name)
    TextView textView;
    @BindView(R.id.image_view_profile)
    ImageView imageViewProf;
    @BindView(R.id.image_view_radio_btn)
    ImageView imageViewRB;

    private boolean isChecked = false;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bind(final Human Human) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                humanClick.onSelectedHumanClick(Human);
            }
        });
        textView.setText(human.getName());
    }

    public void changeRBImage() {
        if(!isChecked){
            isChecked = true;
            imageViewRB.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(imageViewRB.getContext(), R.drawable.selected));
        }
        else{
            isChecked = false;
            imageViewRB.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(imageViewRB.getContext(), R.drawable.not_selected));
        }
    }
}
```

My Recycler is defined inside a fragment here:

```
public class HumansFragment implenets HumanClick{



@BindView(R.id.recycler_humans)
RecyclerView humansRecyclerView;

@Inject
MyAdapter myAdapter;

.
.
.


public void loadHumans(List<Human> humans) {
    myAdapter.init(Humans, this);
    humansRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    humansRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}


@Override
public void humansClick(Human human) {
        //TODO
}
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You can try using a for loop to disable other items of the RecyclerView except the one selected. And on click of the same enable all.

Comment: Can you show some code please.

Comment: Can you please post your code where the recyclerView is defined?

Comment: @AmitJangid can you give me the code example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking in something like this, using setOnItemClickListener and check the position of the item clicked. The position is the index of the item clicked check the last event and new, if both are equal change color, if not dont do anything like disabling.

```
 private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position = " + getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     //go through each item if you have few items within recycler view
    if(getLayoutPosition()==0){
       //Do whatever you want here

    }else if(getLayoutPosition()==1){ 
       //Do whatever you want here         

    }else if(getLayoutPosition()==2){

    }else if(getLayoutPosition()==3){

    }else if(getLayoutPosition()==4){

    }else if(getLayoutPosition()==5){

    }

    //or you can use For loop if you have long list of items. Use its length or size of the list as 
    for(int i = 0; i<exampleList.size(); i++){

    }


  }
  }
```

Or something smaller

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
 new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, recyclerView ,new 
 RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // do whatever
  }

  @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
    // do whatever
  }
})
);
```